# analytic function on convex open subset of complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is analytic on a open convex subset $\Omega$ of the complex plane $C$ and $|f'|\leq1$ on $\Omega$

I want to show $|f(a)-f(b)| \leq |a-b|$ for $a, b \in \Omega$

How I can use the convex condition?

Comment: If $\gamma$ is a path in $\Omega$ connecting $a$ and $b$, then $$f(b) - f(a) = \int_{\gamma} f'(z)\,dz.$$

Answer (score 1):

Convex implies the line $ L= \{ ta+(1-t)b \mid 0<t<1 \}$ is entirely contained in $\Omega$. Now apply the trivial bound to
$$ \int_L f'(z) \, dz = f(b)-f(a). $$